# mmenu not working, looks like regular html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I wrote an html page just to try the mmenu in visual studio. When I run the code, before clicking **open the menu**, all I see is regular html. Clicking **open the menu** doesn't do anything.  [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#myMenu">Open the menu</a>
        <nav id="myMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Enter</a>
                    <ul class="vertical">
                        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Continue as guest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-menu").mmenu({
            // Options
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in  my project I have these files:

**JS**

1. jquery-1.11.3.min.js
2. jquery.mmenu.all.min.js

**CSS**

1. jquery.mmenu.all.css

I am not connected to the internet when I run the code. 
Do I have to be using Sass? I saw it mentioned somewhere in the mmenu site, but have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1):

As per mmenu docs,

> "The plugin automatically binds a click event that opens the menu to
>   every A element that links to the menu."

For this purpose you must use the menu's id in the href attribute of the trigger element.

```
<a href="#myMenu">Open the menu</a>
  <nav id="myMenu">
  </nav>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/045jL1gh/)

Comment: I don't get it. I **do** have that  in line 10. Right after body and div opening tags.

Comment: Did you change it in your script?

Comment: Yeah. I told you. Same results.):

Comment: Can you copy your code into jsfiddle and refer the link here?
It must be a simple issue.And also what server you use for running code?Also check in browser dev tool whether the JS lib and css are loaded.

Comment: I hope this works as this is the first time I'm using jsFiddle. [Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/AhnJaeHee/dssxptkf/#&togetherjs=nEx9R2Uoty). I'm using my own computer to run the code.

Comment: In Chrome f12> Sources, I see the CSS and JS libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101521/discussion-between-raghu-and-rosa).